# Any way to express function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a function

```
void fun1(int i, char j, char* c, long l) {...}
```

. Is there any way I can express the parameter list from *fun1* without writing it out myself?

```
void fun2(char additionalVar, std::getAllThoseParameters(fun1))
```

For context, my final goal is to write something like this:

```
void fun1(int i, char j, char* c, long l) {...}

template<typename Fn, Fn fn> 
 void fun2(char additionalVar, std::getAllThoseParameters){
  ...
  fn(std::getAllThoseParameters);
}
int main(){
   fun2('a',1,'c',NULL,5l);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think normally you just write a template that takes a so-called "parameter pack", which allows any mixture of types, then let it fail to instantiate in the case where the parameters passed aren't compatible with the signature of `fun1`. But how do you expect the template parameters `Fn` and `fn` to be deduced from that call `fun2('a',1,'c',NULL,5l);`? The thing you do to sort that out might affect the answer.

Comment: The best so far is to be explicit. 
    fun2<typeof &fun1>(...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variadic function template and parameter packs.

```
void fun1(int i, char j, char* c, long l) {}

template<typename Fn, typename ... Args> 
 void fun2(Fn fn, char additionalVar, Args ... args){
  fn(args ...);
}

void fun3(int i, char j) {}

int main(){
   fun2(fun1, 'a',1,'c',nullptr,5l);
   fun2(fun3, 'a',1,'c');
   fun2( [](int i, char j, double k) -> void {}, 'a',1,'c', 1.0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but I would prefer not sending a function pointer.  It is in my case important to enable the possibility for the compiler to inline fn.

Comment: @Johan, if by "inline", you mean to use a lambda function, that's not a problem. See my update.

Comment: By inlining I mean compiler inlining, as in replacement of the function call with the code contained in the function. For that to happen it must be known statically which function is going to be called.

Comment: @Johan, the function will be known at compiler time. An inline function should work just fine.

Comment: An inline function should work fine yes, agreed. However in the case of fun1 I want the function NOT call fun1, but instead have the compiler inline it for me (or at least give the compiler the possibility do do so). 

As far as I understand it this can not happen, as the instantiated fun2<fun1> can take as argument any function matching the signature of fun1. This is the reason for function pointer not being a good option, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you ask, but may solve your problem:

```
void fun1(int i, char j, char* c, long l) {...}

template<typename Ret, typename ... Args> 
void fun2(Ret (*fn) (Args...), char additionalVar, Args... args){
    fn(args...);
}

int main(){
   fun2(&fun1, 'a', 1, 'c', NULL, 5l);
}
```

or simply

```
template<typename Fn, Fn fn, typename ... Ts> 
void fun2(char additionalVar, Ts&&... args){
    fn(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

with

```
int main(){
   fun2<decltype(&func1), &func1>('a', 1, 'c', NULL, 5l);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42. Using a function pointer however would make it impossible for the compiler to inline fn, which is important for me.

Comment: @chris Nice. Thank you!